# Let Cell appear and disappear depending on TextInput

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have 2 prototype cells.

One represents all the comments from the post.
This is initially presented.

If a user writes an "@" sign, a tableview with users he can choose to link appears.

My Problem is that the cells with users never disappear.

I want them to disappear if a cell is touched or if the user deletes the @ sign.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (commentTextField.text?.contains("@"))! {
        let cellForUser = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath) as! SuggestUserTableViewCell

        let user = usersSuggestion[indexPath.row]

        cellForUser.userSuggested = user
        return cellForUser
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
        let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
        let user = users[indexPath.row]

        cell.tapMore.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.comment = comment
        cell.postId = postId
        cell.user = user
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell

    }


}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let caption = commentTextField.text
    let words = caption?.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    for var word in words! {
        if word.hasPrefix("@") {
            word = word.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters)
            return usersSuggestion.count

        }
    }
    return comments.count

}
```

Additionally I would like to have the cell2 with the users at the bottom, currently both start at the very top of the screen.

And I don't want to let the comments ever disappear, just decrease the opaqueness of the cell.

cell2 should disappear as soon as cell touched or @ sign deleted.

Thanks in advance

**Update Code**

```
   @objc func textFieldDidChange() {

    doSearch()

    if let commentText = commentTextField.text , !commentText.isEmpty {
        sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)

        sendButton.isEnabled = true
        return
    }

    sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControlState.normal)
    sendButton.isEnabled = false
}

func doSearch() {
    let caption = commentTextField.text

    let words = caption?.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    for var word in words! {
        if word.hasPrefix("@") {
            word = word.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters)

            self.usersSuggestion.removeAll()
            API.User.suggestUsers(withText: word, completion: { (user) in

                self.usersSuggestion.insert(user, at: 0)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            self.usersSuggestion.removeAll()
        }else {
            self.usersSuggestion.removeAll()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the check for "@" in CellForRowAt, I think you should add a target to your text field with the action .editingChanged so that the check will fire each time there is a change. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have, the rest is working fine, I ll show it in my code